# Dafny assertion error with forall statement

Tags: logic, dafny, forall

```
assert forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length && index > 0 && a[0] != 0 ==> a[k] != k;
```

Consider the above dafny code. Assume that a is an array of natural numbers. In English, I'd like to say "For all k such that 0 <= k < a.Length where index > 0 and a[0] != 0 then, a[k] != k". When I write this I get an assertion error in dafny. Why might I be getting this assertion error. Can I not have a quantifier like this and if not, how am I able to quantify variables in dafny assertions?

Comment: What code are you attaching this to? And also what exactly is the error message you're getting? (Failed to prove, or syntax error, or what?)

Comment: @ENV there's really not enough information here to answer this question. The assertion is syntactically correct, but I don't see why it should be true for an arbitrary array of numbers. Do you have some other facts about `a` available? Also, what is `index` and why is it relevant?

Comment: I was able to come up with a different invariant and some lemmas that ultimately built up to this statement. Thanks for your help @JamesWilcox!